Cómo mostrar el promedio en mi página para actualizar
Al momento de enviar un registro este método me hace lo que quiero, que es mediante varios select option seleccionar un valor el cual es un numero entero y en un campo marcado como hidden colocar el resultado de la suma de dichos números o campos y en otro campo que si es visible  sacar el promedio de dicha suma, el problema esta en que cuando yo quiero aplicar el mismo método para mi formulario actualizar al momento de hacer las operaciones ya no las hace y al momento de inspeccionar la pagina me muestra este error `Uncaught TypeError: document.calculadora.nota1 is undefined
Suma http://localhost/SIDIEA/admin/calificaciones/show.php?id=1&&id_docente=1&&id_materia=1:851
onchange http://localhost/SIDIEA/admin/calificaciones/show.php?id=1&&id_docente=1&&id_materia=1:1`
Todo esta en un mismo archivo
Formmulario para actualizar

<form action="<?= APP_URL ?>/app/controllers/calificaciones/update.php" name="calculadora" method="post">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="calificacion_id" value="<?= $id_calificacion; ?>" hidden>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="estudiante_id" value="<?= $id_estudiante; ?>" hidden>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="materia_id" value="<?= $id_materia_get; ?>" hidden>
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="docente_id" value="<?= $id_docente_get; ?>" hidden>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">Corte</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="corte" value="<?= $calificacion['corte']; ?>">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">Examen</label>
       <select class="form-control" onchange="Suma()" name="nota1">
        <option value="0" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "0" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>0</option>
        <option value="1" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "3" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>3</option>
        <option value="4" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "4" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>4</option>
        <option value="5" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "5" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>5</option>
        <option value="6" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "6" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>6</option>
        <option value="7" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "7" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>7</option>
        <option value="8" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "8" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>8</option>
        <option value="9" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "9" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9</option>
        <option value="10" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "10" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>10</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">Participación</label>
        <select class="form-control" onchange="Suma()" name="nota2">
         <option <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>---Seleccione un puntaje---</option>
         <option value="1" <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>1</option>
         <option value="2" <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>2</option>
         <option value="3" <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "3" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>3</option>
         <option value="4" <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "4" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>4</option>
         <option value="5" <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "5" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>5</option>
         <option value="6" <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "6" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>6</option>
         <option value="7" <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "7" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>7</option>
         <option value="8" <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "8" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>8</option>
         <option value="9" <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "9" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9</option>
         <option value="10" <?= $calificacion['nota2'] == "10" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>10</option>
        </select>
       </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="">Tareas</label>
       <select class="form-control" onchange="Suma()" name="nota3">
        <option <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>---Seleccione un puntaje---</option>
        <option value="1" <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>1</option>
        <option value="2" <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "3" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>3</option>
        <option value="4" <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "4" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>4</option>
        <option value="5" <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "5" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>5</option>
        <option value="6" <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "6" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>6</option>
        <option value="7" <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "7" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>7</option>
        <option value="8" <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "8" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>8</option>
        <option value="9" <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "9" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9</option>
        <option value="10" <?= $calificacion['nota3'] == "10" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>10</option>
       </select>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Proyectos</label>
      <select class="form-control" onchange="Suma()" name="nota4">
       <option <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>---Seleccione un puntaje---</option>
       <option value="1" <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>1</option>
       <option value="2" <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>2</option>
       <option value="3" <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "3" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>3</option>
       <option value="4" <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "4" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>4</option>
       <option value="5" <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "5" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>5</option>
       <option value="6" <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "6" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>6</option>
       <option value="7" <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "7" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>7</option>
       <option value="8" <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "8" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>8</option>
       <option value="9" <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "9" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9</option>
       <option value="10" <?= $calificacion['nota4'] == "10" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>10</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Exposición</label>
      <select class="form-control" onchange="Suma()" name="nota5">
       <option <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>---Seleccione un puntaje---</option>
       <option value="1" <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>1</option>
       <option value="2" <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>2</option><option value="3" <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "3" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>3</option>
       <option value="4" <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "4" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>4</option>
       <option value="5" <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "5" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>5</option>
       <option value="6" <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "6" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>6</option>
       <option value="7" <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "7" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>7</option>
       <option value="8" <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "8" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>8</option>
       <option value="9" <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "9" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9</option>
       <option value="10" <?= $calificacion['nota5'] == "10" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>10</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Conducta</label>
      <select class="form-control" onchange="Suma()" name="nota6">
       <option <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>---Seleccione un puntaje---</option>
       <option value="1" <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>1</option>
       <option value="2" <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>2</option>
       <option value="3" <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "3" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>3</option>
       <option value="4" <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "4" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>4</option>
       <option value="5" <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "5" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>5</option>
       <option value="6" <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "6" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>6</option>
       <option value="7" <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "7" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>7</option>
       <option value="8" <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "8" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>8</option>
       <option value="9" <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "9" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9</option>
       <option value="10" <?= $calificacion['nota6'] == "10" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>10</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Hoja de evaluación</label>
      <select class="form-control" onchange="Suma()" name="nota7" >
       <option <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>---Seleccione un puntaje---</option>
       <option value="1" <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "1" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>1</option>
       <option value="2" <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "2" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>2</option>
       <option value="3" <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "3" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>3</option>
       <option value="4" <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "4" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>4</option>
       <option value="5" <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "5" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>5</option>
       <option value="6" <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "6" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>6</option>
       <option value="7" <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "7" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>7</option>
       <option value="8" <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "8" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>8</option>
       <option value="9" <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "9" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>9</option>
       <option value="10" <?= $calificacion['nota7'] == "10" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>10</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Promedio total</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nota8" value="<?= $calificacion['nota8']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Calcule el promedio para actualizar">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>                  
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Actualizar</button>
  </div>
</form>

'Script' para realizar la suma
<script>
function Suma() {
var nota1 = document.calculadora.nota1.value;
var nota2 = document.calculadora.nota2.value;
var nota3 = document.calculadora.nota3.value;
var nota4 = document.calculadora.nota4.value;
var nota5 = document.calculadora.nota5.value;
var nota6 = document.calculadora.nota6.value;
var nota7 = document.calculadora.nota7.value;
try {
nota1 = (isNaN(parseInt(nota1))) ? 0 : parseInt(nota1);
nota2 = (isNaN(parseInt(nota2))) ? 0 : parseInt(nota2);
nota3 = (isNaN(parseInt(nota3))) ? 0 : parseInt(nota3);
nota4 = (isNaN(parseInt(nota4))) ? 0 : parseInt(nota4);
nota5 = (isNaN(parseInt(nota5))) ? 0 : parseInt(nota5);
nota6 = (isNaN(parseInt(nota6))) ? 0 : parseInt(nota6);
nota7 = (isNaN(parseInt(nota7))) ? 0 : parseInt(nota7);
document.calculadora.resultado.value = nota1 + nota2 + nota3 + nota4 + nota5 + nota6 + nota7;
document.calculadora.nota8.value = (document.calculadora.resultado.value / 7).toFixed(1);
} catch (e) {}
}
</script>


Solo preguntaré una cosa... cual es el VALOR del PRIMER option ?

En el caso de esto según el id del registro se selecciona una de las opciones del select option osea que por eso hace la pregunta de que si el campo de la base de datos es igual al value entonces se selecciona por defecto dicho valor

de nuevo... CUAL es el VALOR del PRIMER option ? fijate bien...

Si ya vi no esta asignado

y el error dice claramente "document.calculadora.nota1 is undefined"... que no está asignado. Ahora, hay que asignarle un valor, el cual debes controlar como error, incluso si este valor termina siendo vacio, o texto, pero como el resto son valores, asignale un valor.

Le asigne un valor de 0 con lo cual se puede decir que no debe marcar ese error pero  sigue mandandolo

Y disculpen si soy algo confuso soy algo novato en esto

Debes agregar un [MCVE], esto es un código que permita reproducir el problema tal cual tú lo tienes. Me parece que tu problema es solo de HTML+JS por lo que, en el código de tu pregunta no debería haber código PHP. No obstante, si decides incluirlo debes también incluir las variables asignadas, porque yo no tengo idea que es calificacion['nota1'], en otras palabras, un código que yo pueda copiar, pegar, ejecutar y ver el mismo error que te sale a ti sin aplicar mayor trabajo. Y por último tu HTML tiene un scroll horizontal horrible, eso también debes ordenarlo

actualiza la publicación, además que el código se podría resumen bastante.

Ok gracias, tratare de hacerlo, ya que es la primera vez que publico en esta plataforma y en otras parecidas

Lo unico que realice es hacer el cambio el primer option por esto <option value="0" <?= $calificacion['nota1'] == "0" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>0</option>

Y sigue marcando error

Donde está la declaración de la variable ? no la veo en el código.

Solución
Gracias al ultimo comentario solucione mi error lo unico que hice es colocar la clase notas en mis select y con ello modificar el script que se utilizaba anteriormente por el del ultimo comentario, con ello hice unas modificaciones ya que por cada registro que se obtiene o exista, se genera un formulario de actualización, por ellos las modificaciones en el script, mediante código php le pase la variable id para que no marcara error y se mostrase los datos correspondientes del registro, y eso es todo lo que hice, el problema quedo solucionado
<script>
const notas<?=$id_calificacion;?> = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("form select.notas<?=$id_calificacion;?>"));

function Suma() {
const suma = notas<?=$id_calificacion;?>.reduce((a, i) => a + (Number(i.value) || 0), 0);
const promedio = suma / notas<?=$id_calificacion;?>.length;
document.getElementById("promedio<?=$id_calificacion;?>").value = promedio.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("resultado<?=$id_calificacion;?>").value = suma;
}
</script>


Yay! yo tenía razón xDD

Probé tu código y no da el error que tú señalas, pero si arroja que no existe document.calculadora.resultado y al revisar el HTML no lo veo por ninguna parte.
Es muy probable a que tu problema se deba a que no estas utilizando getElementById, querySelector o algo similar, si no que estas accediendo a los elementos directamente por su nombre (leer sobre este problema aquí)
Si bien no tengo certeza de porque se produce tu error, lo que te puedo ofrecer es un código que si funciona:
<?php
   
    $items = array('nota1' => "Examen", 'nota2' => "Participación", 'nota3' => "Tareas" ,'nota4' => "Proyectos" ,'nota5' => "Exposición", 'nota6' => "Conducta",'nota7' => "Hoja de evaluación");

    //variables fake, solo para pruebas
    $id_calificacion=1;$id_estudiante=1;$id_materia_get=1;$id_docente_get=1;
    $calificacion = array('nota1' => 1, 'nota2' => 3, 'nota3' => 6 ,'nota4' => 1 ,'nota5' => 1, 'nota6' => 1,'nota7' => 7,'nota8' => 7);
?>
<form action="<?= APP_URL ?>/app/controllers/calificaciones/update.php" name="calculadora" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="calificacion_id" value="<?= $id_calificacion; ?>" >
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="estudiante_id" value="<?= $id_estudiante; ?>" >
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="materia_id" value="<?= $id_materia_get; ?>" >
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="docente_id" value="<?= $id_docente_get; ?>" >
        <input id="resultado" name="resultado" type="hidden" />
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Corte</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="corte" value="<?= $calificacion['corte']; ?>">
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php foreach($items as $key => $value): ?>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for=""><?= $value ?></label>
                    <select class="form-control notas" onchange="Suma()" name="<?= $key ?>">
                         <option <?= $calificacion[$key] == "" ? 'selected' : '' ?>>---Seleccione un puntaje---</option>
                        <?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++): ?>
                            <option value='<?= $i ?>' <?= $calificacion[$key] == $i ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?= $i ?></option>
                        <?php endfor;?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Promedio total</label>
                <input id="nota8" type="text" class="form-control" name="nota8" value="<?= $calificacion['nota8']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Calcule el promedio para actualizar">
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>                  
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Actualizar</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
    const notas = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("form select.notas"));
    function Suma() {
        const suma = notas.reduce((a, i) => a + (Number(i.value) || 0),0);
        const promedio = suma / notas.length;
        //const promedio = suma / notas.filter(i => (Number(i.value) || 0) > 0).length; //promedio solo con las notas existentes
        document.getElementById("nota8").value = promedio.toFixed(1);
        document.getElementById("resultado").value = suma;

    }
</script>


Ok, gracias lo probare
